# Deployed a contract using Remix need to access the abi and function whie developing frontend

Tags: ethereumjs, foundry, wagmi

I have deployed one of my contracts using remix, I have also used the oppenzeplin imports, and while trying to verify I could not cause it could not detect the imports. So I went with making a front end, However, while deploying I did not realize we needed the abi.
Can someone tell me:

1. How to verify the contract directly from  Etherscan if I have imports
2. How can I get the abi of this contract?
3. How can I pass the value in wei in foundry in the script section so I can test and pass the value from the same wallet?

The contract address is https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0xa37720085557b62210985735c0d040ed588d3c52#code

The contract code is

````
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract GameItem is ERC721URIStorage {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
    uint256 timestamp;

    string   []  public nftMetadata;

    uint public supply;

    constructor(uint256 _supply,string [] memory _metadata) ERC721("GameItem", "ITM") {
        timestamp = block.timestamp;
        supply = _supply;
        nftMetadata = _metadata;
    }

    mapping(address => mapping(uint256 => string)) public holders;
    mapping(address => string) public holdersString;

    uint256 decreasevalue = 20;
    uint256 amount = 300;
    
    function newAmount(uint256 decreaseValue, uint256 currentvalue) internal returns(uint256){
        uint256 valuetomultiple = decreaseValue/100;
        uint256 subtractValue = currentvalue * valuetomultiple;
        uint256 newamount = currentvalue - subtractValue;
        decreasevalue += 10;
        return newamount;
    } 

    function getPayableAmount() public view returns(uint256){
        return amount;
    }

    function getTokenURI(address _user) external returns(string memory){
        return holdersString[_user];
    }

    
    
    modifier  PayProperly() {
        require(msg.value >= amount ,"Pay more");
        _;
    }

    function newtokenURI() internal returns (string memory){
        require(nftMetadata.length > 0,"All nfts are minted!");
        string memory nftMetadatavalue = nftMetadata[nftMetadata.length-1];
        nftMetadata.pop();
        return nftMetadatavalue;

    }
 
   


    function awardItem(address player)
        public payable PayProperly
        returns (uint256)
    {
        require(supply != 0,"Supply is over!");
        amount = newAmount(decreasevalue, amount);
        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
        _mint(player, newItemId);
        string memory newTokenURI = newtokenURI();
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, newTokenURI);
        holders[msg.sender][_tokenIds.current()] = newTokenURI;
        holdersString[msg.sender] = newTokenURI;
        supply -= 1;
        _tokenIds.increment();
        
        return newItemId;
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can verify the contract with the help of remix itself. On the bottom left corner you will see the plugin buttton, clicking on that and search verify, then activate the plugin and after compiling the contract you will be able to verify it. Note that you will need to provide the etherscan API key, that you can easily get by loging on to ETherscan.

[image]

2. To get the abi click on this icon

[image: List item]

3. Foundry uses solidity, that means you can write `1 ether` and it will be interpreted as `1 * 10 **18`.

**EDIT: Adding a helper function to convert ETher to wei.**

```
    function toWei(uint etherValue) external pure returns(uint){
         return etherValue * ether; 
      //You can also use "etherValue * 10 **18", it's basically the same under the hood. 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, however while trying to verify it fails. I don't understand why it throws no error. I want to pass wei or GEWI , Does the solidity if we pass 300 or 400 as value in the contract consider it as wei or eth ?

Comment: There might be some bug within the remix, or maybe from your side. I don't usually use remix. Instead, you should also use hardhat verification, much easier.

Comment: Wei is nothing but just a denomination, so `1 ether = 1 * 10 **18 wei`. It's a simple conversion. In your test cases you can add a helper function that multiplies the ether value with `10 **18` and returns this value which will be in Wei. Updating my answer with an example function.